# Additional MySQL queries are run with select statement

Tags: mysql, database, dbeaver

I've got a quiz application that is running several queries to a MySQL database. The backend application is running using Java. Every time the app runs a query to the database, there are additional queries that are being executed that I am not specifying within the application. As a result, this is causing a lot of additional overhead to the database, sometimes resulting in an error.

For example, I've got a 'Questions' table that only contains regular characters, such as the below:

[image]

The application does a simple `SELECT * from Questions` to get the list of questions. However, when that is executed, I can see in the database logs that there are 4 additional queries that are also run (the first I assume is the connectivity to the database), which I have not specified. Those are:

[image]

Could someone tell me why this is happening? Essentially, every query that is run against the database (specified by the application) renders the same exact additional 3 queries that (to me) are coming out of nowhere.

Comment: This aditional queries are used for to set correct properties for a connection. I think that each time you need to execute a query you open new connection, and you close it after the query executed. To avoid this open a connection during application start and do not close it until application finishing - reuse it for all of your queries. The connection will be set (this additional queries will be executed) only once.

Comment: Thank you. Would not closing the connection after each query cause any issues if there are a lot of people accessing my applications (and therefore the database) at the same time? Perhaps this is something that I need to investigate, but would there be any locking of tables or any of that kind of things? Also, the application is being exposed through a series of API endpoints, so in all honesty, I'm not entirely sure how I'd share the connection between the different endpoints.

Comment: *Would not closing the connection after each query cause any issues if there are a lot of people accessing my applications (and therefore the database) at the same time?* Hardly.